# Avoid database round trips when we have more than one user control on aspx page

Tags: asp.net, controls, call

I have more than one user control on my aspx page, and each user control call it's own service or method to display content retrieved from SQL DB. I want to reduce these round trips, and get the job done in one call. Any idea what's the best practice.

Comment: does all user control display the same data(user control for each row) or each control display its own data

Comment: each has it's own data..how about a master user control?? but I am still need ideas..please suggest any

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can put your all select statements in one stored procedure that mean you will hit your database just one time and load the result into a `DataSet` using `SqlAdapter.Fill(MyDataSet)` and pass the each table in your dataset to corresponding user control by creating public property with `DataTable` type

```
public class UserControl_1
{
   private DataTable _dbTable;
   public DataTable dbTable;
   {
      get
      {
          return _dbTable;
      }
      set
      {
         _dbTable = value
      }
   }
}
```

in your page

```
Private DataSet myDataSet;
public void Page_Load(Object sender,EventArgs e)
{
   myDataSet = PopulateData(); // call your stored procedure inside it
   UserControl_1.dbTable = myDataSet.Tables[0];
   UserControl_2.dbTable = myDataSet.Tables[1];

   //... and so on
}
```

I wish that give you a good idea

Comment: Thanks Micro..will let you know if have any questions further.

Comment: sorry..I am still trying that..will let you know ASAP

Comment: I have a new problem. I want this to be highly scalable. So, if I am adding one more User Control, I don't want to change the proc again. I want to send the parameters as a DataTable. But, don't know how...any idea??

Comment: As I understanded from your question one more user control mean one more select statement, becuase as you said **each has it's own data** so you will have to change the stored procedure.